# Как найти все соседние клетки? "Игра жизнь"

Tags: javascript

Пишу игру "Жизнь". Как найти соседние клетки?

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var cell = [
    1, 1, 1, 0,
    1, 0, 1, 0,
    1, 0, 1, 1,
    0, 1, 0, 1
  ];
  var tableContainer = document.querySelector("table");
  var tbodyContainer = tableContainer.querySelector("tbody");
  var createdRow = document.createElement("tr");
  cell.forEach(function(Onecell, i, arr) {
    if (i % 4 === 0) {
      tbodyContainer.appendChild(createdRow);
      createdRow = document.createElement("tr");
    }
    tbodyContainer.appendChild(createdRow);
    var createdCell = document.createElement("td");
    if (Onecell === 0) {
      createdCell.classList.add("dead");
    } else {
      createdCell.classList.add("live");
    }
    // добавляем только что созданый элемент в дерево DOM
    createdRow.appendChild(createdCell);
  });
}
```

```css
td {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
tr {
  display: table-row;
  vertical-align: inherit;
  border-color: inherit;
}
.live,
.dead {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
.live {
  background-color: #adff2f;
}
.dead {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
table {
  border: 4px double black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: о каких клетках идет речь? в чем заключается проблема?

Comment: Хочу чтобы все соседние клетки могли видеть друг друга.

Comment: а почему ты думаешь, что сейчас они не видят друг друга?

Comment: Как тогда реализовать алгоритм. Чтобы клетки умирали от перенаселенности или от их недостачи?

Comment: очень просто, сначала надо определиться с самим алгоритмом

Comment: В этом и проблема, не знаю с чего начать.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44470/discussion-between-grundy-and-spmpl).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

для одномерного массива (не знаю как сказать)... потом в матрицу.
функция для нахождения всех соседних клеток на указанную дальность chec(индекс вокруг которого искать, дальнось, ширина матрицы, высота),  для примера индекс 2, матрица 4 на 4, глубина 1. результат [1,3,5,6,7]

```js
function chec(indx, size, width, height) {
            var s = [],
                x = indx % width,
                y = indx / width | 0;
            size = size || 1;
            for (var i = y - size; i <= y + size; i++) {
                for (var k = x - size; k <= x + size; k++) {
                    var num = k + i * width;
                    i > -1 && i < height && k > -1 && k < width && num < (i * width + width) && num != indx && s.push(num)

                }
            }
            return s
        }
console.log(chec(2, 1, 4, 4) );
```

Comment: А проще можно сделать? Сложно понять твой код.

Answer (score -2):

Воспользуйтесь  в новой переменной.

```
elem.querySelectorAll(value)
```

и уже работайте исходя от нее. так, как  `elem.querySelector(value)` взаимодействует только с 1 (первым найденным =[0]) элементом.

Comment: где использовать эту _новую переменную_?